Change the background colour of BODY element with Javascript
I want to change the background colour of the body element. When I tried with the first, it won't work. But when I tried with the second, it worked perfectly. I want to know the reason.
let x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor

function change() { x = "red"; }


let x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]

function change() { x.style.backgroundColor = "red"; }


Because the first one will be a string, e.g. "white" which, once copied to x no longer has a connection to the body tag.

try myStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style and that should work. That's the difference between assigning object (pointer) vs property (copy)

document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red' does that just fine... You can't have more than 1 body anyway. There is really no reason to place that into a variable.

The first one, x is a value.  The second one, x is an object.  See: working with objects (MDN)

In your firts example, you’re assigning the background color of the  to the variable x but modifying x doesn’t affect the  element because it simply reassigns x, without updating the actual style of the page.
